# Is there a classification of non-compact Lie Groups? I am interested specifically in subgroups of GL(n,R).

Tags: group-theory, lie-groups, lie-algebras

I know there is a classification of compact Lie groups, and that the subgroup structure of the compact Lie groups is well understood.  What is the state of knowledge about non-compact Lie groups?  Are they completely classified?  Are all of the subgroups of GL(n,R) classified and understood?

Comment: Classification in which sense? Up to isomorphism (between the subgroups)? Up to conjugation inside $GL_n$? These are distinct questions. By the way you probably mean compact connected Lie groups. Compact Lie groups include all finite groups...

Answer (score 1):

No, non-compact Lie groups are not classified at all. For example, (connected and simply connected) nilpotent Lie groups have only been classified, in terms of nilpotent Lie algebras, up to dimension $7$. For references see [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/21114/low-dimensional-nilpotent-lie-algebras). It is also clear that a classification is impossible in the general case (some people call this "wild", i.e., algebras of wild type, see [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/10481/when-is-a-classification-problem-wild)). By Ado's theorem, nilpotent Lie algebras can be realised as subalgebras of the Lie algebra of strictly upper-triangular Lie algebras, corresponding to the Lie subgroup of upper unitriangular matrices in $GL(n,\mathbb{R})$.